# jquery object not being formed from css #id

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to bring in a css id as a Jquery object.

I am bringing in a button and adding an event handler to it:

test.js:

```
var infobutton = $('#infos');

infobutton.on('click', showinfo);

  function showinfo() {
    if (state !== 'info') {
      setstate('info');
    } else {
      setstate('play');
    }
    //pause timer
    startTimer = false;
  }
```

test.css:

```
.navbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  display: block;
  right: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #060;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#infos {
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 55px;
}
```

test.html:

```
<button id="infos" class="navbutton">i</button>
```

But it's not working. The jQuery object is not being created.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `var` from in front of the second `var infobutton`.

```
var infobutton = $('#infos');

infobutton.on('click', showinfo);

  function showinfo() {
    if (state !== 'info') {
      setstate('info');
    } else {
      setstate('play');
    }
    //pause timer
    startTimer = false;
  }
```

You only need to declare the variable with `var` the first time.  The second `var` is confusing the JS because that implies you are reassigning the variable to a different value and so your `click` event handler is not being bound - you just need `infobutton` to reference the variable.

Comment: Thank you but Sorry that was not supposed to be there. A mistake when copying it over. In my acutal code it is not there.

Comment: @VickiT05 it should work then, unless either a) your code in `showinfo()` doesn't work properly or b) the `#infos` element is added dynamically after the event is bound.  Add the line `console.log('showinfo() fired');` to the `showinfo()` function and see if it's being fired and report back.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're getting an error. If you look at your browser's console, you'll see something like this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

This is because of this line:

```
var infobutton.on('click', showinfo);
```

You use the `var` keyword to create a variable. You aren't creating one here. You're using an existing one; when Javascript gets to the `.` character, it thinks "this isn't allowed as a variable name", so it stops. The rest of your code is never executed.

All you need is this:

```
infobutton.on('click', showinfo);
```

From this we learn one crucial lesson:

**Always check the error console.**

Comment: Thank you but I made a mistake when copying my code over, that var is not supposed to be there.

Also, I'm not getting any errors in my console log.

Comment: @VickiT05 From which we learn a second crucial lesson: always copy the right code across! The next question is: are you running the code when the DOM is ready?